# how to write a php code interminal

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oracle10g

I am getting this exception from fetching record through database based on column portfolio
Query:

```
String queryString=    "select entity  from   " +Name + " entity WHERE entity."+Column+" = "+ searchId.toString();
Query query = _em.createQuery(queryString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Many things are wrong here and a lot of important information is missing (entity code?).

1. `className` in your example should be just `Portfolio` instead of `class com.hexgen.orm.Portfolio` (assuming `Portfolio` is entity's name, which doesn't have to be the same as class name). If you are using `someEntity.getClass().getName()` to get it, change to `someEntity.getClass().getSimpleName()`
2. `searchColumn` should be the field name of `Portfolio` class, not column name in the database. Asssuming `PORTFOLIO` column is mapped to `portfolio` field, it should be `portfolio`.

   `String queryString = "select entity from " + simpleClassName + " entity WHERE entity." + searchColumn + " = :searchId";
   Query query = _em.createQuery(queryString);
   query.setParameter("searchId", searchId.toString());`
3. If you don't switch to using query parameters, `searchId.toString()` should be enclosed in single quotes.

So, the valid query should look something like this

```
select entity from Portfolio entity WHERE entity.portfolio = 'HEXAGON20'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your query syntax and if you look at the message it's quite explicit:
You build your query with

```
"select entity  from   " +className + " entity WHERE entity."+searchColumn+" = "+ searchId.toString();
```

Which gives

```
select entity from class com.hexgen.orm.Portfolio entity WHERE entity.PORTFOLIO = HEXAGON20
```

1- the `class` should not be there. Ir looks like it comes from the variable `className`.

2- `HEXAGON20` is a string value that should be `'HEXAGON20'`

Comment: Can you post the sql string that does the error ? also post the entity bean class.